# How to analyse Jmeter jp@gc graphs

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am new in JMeter tool , I have installed JMeter plugin for graphs.
But it is displaying as shown below , Can anyone help me for the best way to analyse JMeter reports?
[Composite graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raA5n.png)

[Transactions per Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JajE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter requests on Rows tab or aggregate them. It will allow to remove mess on graph and show particular sampler results. Also it's better to increase load / test duration to get more points on graphs.

Regarding actual graphs:

- "Transaction per Second" shows few spices no more than 1 tps (transactions per seconds). It may be worth to increare load significantly to get more representative data.
- "Composite Graph" shows that you have a lot of requests for static files. It may be worth to remove samplers for static files like *.css, *.js, *.git and etc.